# Find the last activity on a conversation with the microsoft bot

Tags: botframework

Is it possible to find the last activity on a conversation, using Microsoft Bot.

```
https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/esxgfvjbkmkmljbjh-d/activities?watermark=10
```

I need to send a paginated response to the client for a conversation. Using a watermark, it will allow me to get all the activities after a certain watermark value. But this will not help in finding the activities in a watermark range. And moreover, how to identify, what should be the initial watermark value?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the documentation about DirectLine [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-api-reference?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365&view=azure-bot-service-4.0#get-activities), currently the only way to get the latest activity is by requesting several times by changing the watermark value:

> Clients should page through the available activities by advancing the
> watermark value until no activities are returned.

Comment: But that is a very crude way to find the latest activity. Any better way available?

Answer (score 0):

The temporary cache of messages in the Direct Line channel is not intended to be a persistent store, but only as a connection reliability mechanism.  If you need to retrieve conversation activities at a later time, you should be using a **Transcript Store** and the **SendConversationHistoryAsync** api as demonstrated in this sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/22.conversation-history/